# JUnit 5 / Intellij / custom test engine / method selection issue

Tags: intellij-idea, junit5, parameterized

I have written a custom JUnit 5 test engine for parameterized testing at the test class level. I have found an issue I can seem to resolve.

When using IntelliJ and running the test class, everything works...

[IntelliJ test window when running test class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIxZd.png)

When I run a specific parameter, everything works...

[IntelliJ test window when running test parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1dnqy.png)

When I run a specific method for a specific parameter, all test methods run...

[IntelliJ test window when running test method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joEW3.png)

Every node in the hierarchy has a `UniqueId`, so I would expect IntelliJ to use a `UniqueIdSelector`, but debugging shows that it's using a `MethodSelector`

[Engine Discovery Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5xVG.png)

If the method had parameters, then I could use the `methodParameterType` field to filter... but in this scenario, there are no test method parameters.

Thoughts? Anyone experience this issue? Is it a core IntelliJ issue/limitation or JUnit 5 issue/limitation?

Comment: IntelliJ is doing a decent job with JUnitPlatform support but not a perfect one. Especially, they make some assumptions about the structure of a test hierarchy that are true for plain Jupiter, but not necessarily for other engines. Sometimes behaviour changes when you configure "Run tests using IntelliJ IDEA" (instead of Gradle (default) or vice versa. If that does not help, submitting a bug in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues. Most of my reports have been tackled over time, so I recommend to take your chances.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem. By taking a look into the source code of IntelliJ, I discovered two solutions to make IntelliJ use the `UniqueIdSelector`.

1. Use a `MethodSource` or `ClassSource` which points to a method or class which is **not** annotated with [`@Testable`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.10.0/api/org.junit.platform.commons/org/junit/platform/commons/annotation/Testable.html).
2. Use the same source as you have used for the parent node. For example, you could make every test use the test class as the source, instead of the individual methods.

Both solutions have downsides, of course. Removing the `@Testable` annotation means you can no-longer trigger the test from the source file in IntelliJ. Using the class as the test source for all nodes means you can no-longer jump to the method in the source code.

PS: I assume you have created [IDEA-317561](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317561)? I also created [IDEA-337243](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-337243). Just for reference.

Comment: Correct, I created https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-317561